# Display complete Rmarkdown chunk in a knitr Rmd file (inlcuding chunk header)

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

How can I display a complete Rmarkdown chunk in a **knitr** Rmd file including the chunk header etc., i.e., treat it as verbatim code which should not be evaluated. What I want an output such as

````
```{r, results = 'asis'}
some_code
```
````

I want to have this even after running the file through **knitr** as I want to show how to set up the chunk in a tutorial. I think I've read a solution somewhere but cannot find it anymore.

All my current attempts have failed. I've tried to wrap the code in another 
``` environment and to indent the code by 4 spaces. At best I would also like to have R syntax highlighting, i.e., I would like to use the option r for the code chunk.

Comment: Maybe you can include it as a comment

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908158/show-an-r-markdown-chunk-in-the-final-output

Comment: I recommend Scott's answer to the post http://stackoverflow.com/q/19908158/559676