# Adding non-blog files in a blogdown Web site

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I am trying to construct a Web site with *blogdown*, Hugo, and the `xmin` theme. I would like to store some Markdown files in a subdirectory, say `content/misc/`, such that they are **not** going to be treated as blog entries (e.g., they will be pointed to specifically on some `_index.md` pages).

How can I do this for single files or for all files in a subdirectory of `content/`? I know I can kind of hide them directly in the `content/` directory, however this makes structuring the project clumsy and difficult.

I suspect this will be possible with specific templates, but is there an easier, much simpler way to handle this requirement? Or are there more appropriate themes to make it possible?

Comment: If you only want to list some url and not the content, you can put them in the "static" folder so that you're sure they are not processed. Otherwise, on your github account...?

Comment: If you want to show the content, you can put your code inside a chunk. There are a few examples about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908158/show-an-r-markdown-chunk-in-the-final-output#1994. You can also find some tips about it on my github: https://github.com/statnmap/Rmarkdown_tips

Comment: @SébastienRochette These are `.Rmd` files that need to be processed, so putting them in the `static` folder is no option. And they are *not* code chunks. I looked at your links, but did not find anything obviously useful. Please, if you think you have an answer, put it here explicitly. It appears I found a solution by prepending file names with an underscore `_`, but I have to check a bit more carefully.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Normally, only Rmd that are in "post" folder (sometimes "blog" folder) are treated as blog post. All the other are normal pages that you can directly link in your menu. If you want a special folder like "misc", create a template for that. Look at theme "future-imperfect", there is a special post type called "itemized". I think this is the way you want to do it. I hope... ;)

Answer (score 2):

If there are some pages that you want to show with a common format, but you do  not want them to be listed in your blog articles list

## Simple solution: use the default template

To use the default template, you just need to add this "misc" folder in "content" with all your Rmd inside. Then, there will be a page listing all the articles of this type at "myblog.com/misc/".

## Advanced solution: use a specific template

If you want to have a specific template for these pages.

- If it does not exists, create a "layouts" folder at the root of your project.
- Inside "layouts", create a "misc" folder
- Inside "misc", create a "list.html" file if you want that your page "myblog.com/misc/" shows a list of your pages with this category
- You also need to create a "single.html" if you want a specific way of showing these single articles.

To have ideas what to put inside these two files, you can directly start with the template of your own theme (https://github.com/yihui/hugo-xmin/tree/master/layouts/_default). As I said, you can also look at the "itemized" type of "hugo-future-imperfect" (https://github.com/statnmap/hugo-future-imperfect/tree/master/layouts/itemized), or what I propose for sticky pages on "hugo-statnmap-theme" (https://github.com/statnmap/hugo-statnmap-theme/tree/master/layouts/sticky_pages)

Comment: And as I said, I am looking for a simple solution; I do not want to define templates, layouts, or care for listing pages. The rather inelegant solution I described above will have to be sufficient, I guess. Anyway, thanks for proposing this more comprehensive solution.